# awk in non-interactive is leaving some data missing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, fflush

I'm running an awk command in a shell script, and it's breaking the datafile. All of the data doesn't load, and there's a newline character at the end of each line.

```
awk -v name="$filename" -v batch="$BATCHNAME" -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{$2=batch;print > (name".locked.concur")}' $filename.locked.concur
```

If I run this as a command, it works perfectly.

I've just found that i can use fflush() and it seems to have solved the issue.

So now i have:

```
awk -v name="$filename" -v batch="$BATCHNAME" -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{$2=batch;print > (name".locked.concur") fflush()}' $filename.locked.concur
```

Am I setting myself up for disaster?

Also, the file is renamed to $filename.locked.concur0  --  I'm guessing this zero is the exit code that's returned from fflush? How do I get rid of this 0?

full code:

```
for filename in `cat ${INFILEDIR}/file_list_concur`

do

rm -f $OHAP_DAT/bad/$filename.bad

##Create Batchname based on filename

BATCH_GROUP=`ls $filename.locked.concur |cut -d '_' -f 1`
BATCH_DATE=`ls $filename.locked.concur |cut -d '_' -f 2`
BATCHNAME=${BATCH_GROUP}_Concur_${BATCH_DATE}

echo 'Batch Date = '$BATCH_DATE
echo 'Batch Group = '$BATCH_GROUP
echo 'Batch Name = '$BATCHNAME
echo 'File Name = ' $filename

gawk -v name="$filename" -v batch="$BATCHNAME" -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{$2=batch;print > (name".locked.concur");}' $filename.locked.concur


##End Batchname

sqlldr $ORACLE_PW control=$XXOH_TOP/bin/XXOH_AP_CONCUR_IMPORT_CTL.ctl \
              data=$OHAP_DAT/in/$filename.locked.concur \
              log=$OHAP_DAT/log/$filename.log \
              bad=$OHAP_DAT/bad/$filename.bad \
                bindsize=512000 << end_of_sqlldr
end_of_sqlldr

if [ -f $OHAP_DAT/bad/$filename.bad ]
then
  echo \!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  echo \!! 'date'
  echo \!! SQL*Loader bad file was found!!
  echo \!! Script $filename Failed - BAD FILE!
  echo \!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is indeed that you are reading from and writing to the same file. this should work better:

```
gawk ... print > (name".locked.concur.tmp")}' $filename.locked.concur
mv -f $filename.locked.concur.tmp $filename.locked.concur
```

better still:

```
gawk ... print}' $filename.locked.concur > $filename.locked.concur.tmp
mv -f $filename.locked.concur.tmp $filename.locked.concur
```

Comment: So adding that semicolon for some reason is bringing back the issue of the newline characters and the incomplete output.  I'm guessing the buffer still has the rest of the file before the script moves on.

Also, I won't be writing over the same file, earlier in the code, $filename is defined by a list of files, and essentially changes at each new file that i'll be parsing..

Comment: The `fflush()` is a red herring, you shouldn't need it here. By adding it without the semicolon you changed the name of the output file, which made it different than the name of the input file, which is why it started working. You say that the filename changes, but the awk code you're showing is using the `-v` argument to always set the output file name to be the same as the input file name --- at least that's how it a appears.

Comment: thanks for adding the rest of the code. you do change $filename each time through the loop, but for any single time through, as @jas says, your gawk is reading from and writing to the same file, which causes the messed up output you're seeing.

Comment: I added the better still code - it is working like a charm.  I wish i hadn't made it more complicated for myself.  Thanks a ton for the explanation.  Also, would you know why this works when i run the command in an interactive terminal vs. not working when running as a script?

Comment: most likely you need to add that the script should be run in `bash` as your first script line. do `which bash` then put `#!` and the result, e.g., if `which bash` gives `/bin/bash`, put `#!/bin/bash` as your first script line.